# What is the best way to save the callback in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, callback

When I log in, I use callback and save the clients like this:

```
public List<UserEN> Login(UserEN _user, ref string message)
            {
                List<UserEN> authorizationList = new List<UserEN>();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_user._userName))
                {
                    try
                    { 
                       // string message = string.Empty;
                        lock (locker)
                        {
                            callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ISaadiqinCallback>();

                            //remove the old client
                            if (clients.Keys.Contains(_user._userName))
                                clients.Remove(_user._userName);
                            //Adding the clients with userName and callback channel
                            clients.Add(_user._userName, callback);
                            //Get the authorization list from database
                           authorizationList =  new LoginBal().Login(_user, ref message);

                            //send the list to the client
                            //callback.BroadcastToClient(authorizationList);    
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return authorizationList;
            }
```

After logged in the process ends. 
Now when I try to do some transaction in my system I am checking this method:

```
private bool Override()
        {
            bool isOverrideSuccess = false;
            foreach (var client in clients)
            {
                ISaadiqinCallback cb;// = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ISaadiqinCallback>();
                clients.TryGetValue(client.Key, out cb);
                //call DB
                if (cb.Equals(client.Value) && "Asif" == client.Key)
                {
                   callback.NotifyUser("Override required.");
                }
            }
            return isOverrideSuccess;
        }
```

Obviously, callback is null. Because when I do the transaction it does not go to Login method and won't initialize the callback.
So, what is the best way to save the callback in login method so that I can use it in Override method.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the client sync method on following webpage.  Passing a State object to the call back method will allow the event to modify parameters so the the main function can read the changes. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Generally it's better to have WCF manage concurrency via say `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]` than using `lock()` in case you forget to add it somewhere